Composite FK with 1 column common in both parent and child
I have a parent and child relationship as follows, where Table 1 is the parent and Table 2 is the child. There is only 1 column common in both parent and child tables. For this FK relationship, can I check that the child table will only link with col1 to the col1 in the parent table?
FK_Table2(col1, col2) references PK_Table1(col1, col3)
Thanks & Regards,
ML

Typically a foreign key in the child table points to the primary key in the parent table, as the FK must uniquely identify a single parent. As long as your columns map that relationship correctly - fk_t2(col1,col2) matches pk_t1(col1,col3) - it doesn't matter what the columns are named or what order they appear in either table.
